# How to solve GraphQl ImportError - cannot import name 'gql' from 'gql' in Python?

Tags: python, graphql

I installed GraphQl on Windows 10 Laptop using the below command:

```
pip install --pre gql[all]
```

I tried using the Basic example available on [Official Github Page.](https://github.com/graphql-python/gql) in my Python IDLE.

However, I am getting this ImportError in my IDLE.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'gql' from 'gql'
```

Kindly help in resolving the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

make sure the name of your file you're testing with isn't named something similar to a package you're importing. Just got me when I named my file ariadne.py

https://github.com/mirumee/ariadne/issues/400#issue-662473441

Comment: I had the same issue when I had a folder names 'graphql' in the same directory as my virtual environment folder. Changing the folder name solved the issue.